# Soma de um array e concatenação de valor PHP

Tags: php, array, foreach, soma

Possuo um array dinâmico, nele contém chaves que duplicam (TAG):

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [tag]        => 5x1 Acessori Kids
                    [pedido]     => 6701622409
                    [quantidade] => 2125
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [tag]        => 5x1 Acessori Kids
                    [pedido]     => 6701622422
                    [quantidade] => 3705
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [tag]        => RIABASIC5- 5X1 - 2 COMPOSIÇOES
                    [pedido]     => 6701622411
                    [quantidade] => 3165
                )

        )
```

Gostaria de somar as chaves "quantidade" e agrupar a chave "pedido" com uma virgula, output seria assim:

```
  [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [tag]        => 5x1 Acessori Kids
                    [pedido]     => 6701622422, 6701622409
                    [quantidade] => 5830
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [tag]        => RIABASIC5- 5X1 - 2 COMPOSIÇOES
                    [pedido]     => 6701622411
                    [quantidade] => 3165
                )

        )
```

a soma na key 'quantidade' consegui com a seguinte função:

```
$sum = array_reduce($data, function ($a, $b) {
    isset($a[$b['tag']]) ? $a[$b['tag']]['quantidade'] += $b['quantidade'] : $a[$b['tag']] = $b; 
    return $a;
});

$data = array_values($sum);
```

porém não estou conseguindo concatenar a key 'pedido', que seria para esse exemplo acima:

```
 [pedido]     => 6701622422, 6701622409
```

alguém tem alguma dica?

Comment: Já cogitou em atualizar o PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
$sum = array_reduce($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    if (isset($a[$b['tag']])) {
        $a[$b['tag']]['quantidade'] += $b['quantidade'];
        $a[$b['tag']]['pedido'] .= ",{$b['pedido']}";
    } else {
        $a[$b['tag']] = $b;
    }

    return $a;
});

var_dump( $sum );
```

Comment: Perfeito @Valdeir, muito obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Para futuras pesquisas, consegui somar a key 'quantidade' com o seguinte código:

Variável Data é a variável que contém o array:

```
   $data
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [tag] => 5x1 Acessori Kids - 2017
                [pedido] => 6701622409
                [quantidade] => 2125
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [tag] => 5x1 Acessori Kids - 2017
                [pedido] => 6701622422
                [quantidade] => 3705
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [tag] => RIABASIC5- 5X1 - 2 COMPOSIÇOES
                [pedido] => 6701622411
                [quantidade] => 3165
            )

    )
```

e abaixo a solução

```
$sum = array_reduce($data, function ($a, $b) {
    isset($a[$b['tag']]) ? $a[$b['tag']]['quantidade'] += $b['quantidade'] : $a[$b['tag']] = $b;  
    return $a;
});

echo '<pre>';   
print_r(array_values($sum));
echo '</pre>';
```

porém agora ainda preciso juntar a key 'pedido', agrupar e não somar.

Answer (score 0):

Com duas funções você pode obter a soma dos elementos. [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-column.php) e [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-sum.php). O código fica dessa forma.

```
echo array_sum(array_column($data,'quantidade'));
```

Como você disse que sua versão não suporta `array_column()` podemos fazer um [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php). O código fica dessa forma:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($data as $key) {
    $sum += $key['quantidade'];
}
echo $sum;
```

Supondo que seu array tenha o nome `$data`

Comment: obrigado pelo retorno @Phelipe, eu tentei dessas duas maneiras, o foreach me da a soma total da key, do array completo, não era esse o resultado esperado, enfim, eu consegue com a minha resposta abaixo o somatório da key 'quantidade' agrupando a key 'tag', porém não estou conseguindo concatenar a key 'pedido', conforme meu output desejado.